# Difference between adding parameters to stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, ado.net

I would like to know the difference between these 2 notations.

First of all I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSomething( @zonename varchar(50), @desc varchar(255), @TheNewId int OUTPUT ) AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO a_zone(zonename, descr) VALUES(@zonename, @desc) 
   SELECT @TheNewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()         
END
```

What is the difference if I add parameters in this manner

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("AddSomething", oConn); 
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
SqlParameter oParam1 = Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zonename", sName);
SqlParameter oParam2 = Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", description);
```

and

```
SqlCommand Cmd2 = new SqlCommand("AddSomething", oConn); 
Cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@zonename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = zonename.Text.Trim();
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = desc.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some explanations:

[difference between command Add and AddWithValue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1370191.aspx)

```
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate>@TheDate",conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TheDate",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value="2/1/2007"
```

vs

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheDate","2/1/2007")
```

"Add forces the conversion from string to date as it goes into the parameter. AddWithValue would have simply passed the string on to the SQL Server.

> When using `Parameters.Add` - the SqlDbType is known at compile time
>
> When using `Parameters.AddWithValue` the method has to box and unbox the value to find out its type.
>
> Additional benefits  of the former is that `Add` is a bit more code safe
>   and will assist against SQL injection attacks , code safe in terms
>   that if you try to pass a value that doesn't match the SqlDb type
>   defined - the error will be caught in .Net code and you will not have
>   to wait for the round trip back.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

**Edit**:

example to get an Output-Parameter:

C#

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TheNewId", SqlDbType.Int, int.MaxValue));
cmd.Parameters("@TheNewId").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int theNewID = (int)cmd.Parameters("@TheNewId").Value;
```

VB.Net

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TheNewId", SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue))
cmd.Parameters("@TheNewId").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim theNewID As Int32 = DirectCast(cmd.Parameters("@TheNewId").Value, Int32)
```

Comment: @Tim so u mean both methods are used for passing parameters into stored procedure.

Comment: @user653622: Yes, but not only for stored-procedures but every kind of sql-command. They both have advantages and disadvantages(see links).

Comment: @Tim How can I use the second method for passing output type parameters especially when I won't have any value to pass but instead I would be expecting a value from stored procedure. Specifically in this case cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TheNewId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ???; If i use the second method it would be expecting a value but i have to tell it explicitly don't expect a value u r a output parameter, how should i tell this ? Please help me

Comment: @Tim ur example won't work in asp.net/c# as SqlParameter doesn't have that overload method. Instead this procedure works 

SqlParameter outputParameter1 = new SqlParameter("@NewIntId", SqlDbType.Int);
outputParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd2.Parameters.Add(outputParameter1);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

int valueFromOutputParameter = (int)cmd2.Parameter["@NewIntId"].Value

Answer (score 7):

When you use AddWithValue, the datatype will be worked out (as best possible) based on the types of the variables passed to the method - assuming sName and description are string variables, the params will be passed in as NVARCHAR.

I personally prefer the 2nd approach, being explicit with the data types (plus I actually specify the sizes too) so that they are guaranteed to match the sproc definition and avoid any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: +1 exactly - rather be explicit than let too much "magic" determine your types. Also: if you need to pass in e.g. `DBNull.Value` - how would the ADO.NET runtime be able to figure out what type your "NULL" is going to be!?!?! Be explicit - a tiny bit more typing, but a lot more safety and clarity (think: maintenance!)