# Difference with Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

Basically `Commands` has `Parameters` and parameters has functions like `Add`, `AddWithValue`, and etc. In all tutorials i've seen, i usually noticed that they are using `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`.

```
.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
```

vs

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 1)
```

Is there a reason NOT to use `AddWithValue`? I'd prefer to use that over

```
Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 1
```

since it saves my coding time. So which is better to use? Which is safe to use? Does it improves performance?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question, this looks like the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445663/difference-between-adding-parameters-to-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Have a read of: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With `Add()` method you may restrict user input by specifying type and length of data - especially for `varchar` columns.

```
.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=varName;
```

In case of [AddWithValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (implicit conversion of value) method, it sends nvarchar value to the database.

Comment: Please be advised that there's an overload on .Add that let's you add a SqlParameter/OleDbParameter/DbParameter. When you *omit* the parameter name (by setting it to NULL) in the parameter instance you'll get a nasty performance hit: the .Net framework will create names for you 'Parameter1..x'. Now this seems silly for a SqlParameter, you would want to match the @variable. With OleDbParameter however...

Answer (score 12):

I believe there are also some cons to using AddWithValue which affect the SQL Cache Excection Plan, see the Parameter Length section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Comment: Considering this horrifying sentence in the linked article: 
"By not specifying the length when you're using ParameterCollection.AddWithValue, you can have as many different queries in the plan cache as you have different string lengths."
this may be most valuable response here :)

Comment: that article is pretty old, is that still the behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Using AddWithValue() adds parameter with length of current value. If the length of your parameter value varies often this means new plan is generated every time. This makes your queries run slower(additional time for parsing, compiling) and also causes higher server load.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the AddWithValue for normal cases. And use Add(name, dbtype... only when your column type is different from how .net converts the CLR type.