# Unable to execute cmd.ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Here is the code where i'm trying to retrieve user name using emailid.

```
string query="select name from userdetails where emailid=" + email + ";" ;
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(rd.Read())
{ 
    uname = (string)rd["emailid"];  
    return uname;
}
```

Comment: What is a typical value of `email`, and where does it come from? What does "unable to execute" mean? It doesn't compile? It compiles but throws an exception? What is the exception?

Answer (score 3):

parameterized the value to avoid from `SQL Injection`

```
string query="select name from userdetails where emailid=@email" ;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
```

Try this code snippet:

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlStatement = "select name from userdetails where emailid=@email";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            // other codes
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for proper object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle exception

Comment: For Strings, use Add() instead of AddWithValue!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155004/difference-with-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue

Comment: @FabianBigler thanks for reminding my question back then. I used `AddWithValue()` for normal cases `:)`

Comment: Haha, I didnt see it was you who asked. Funny coindicence.

Answer (score 2):

Put you emailin sigle qoute because it is varchar like this..

```
string query="select name from userdetails where emailid='" + email + "';" ;
```

But this may cause SQL Injection...so use this...

```
 string query="select name from userdetails where emailid=@email;" ;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `select` query like this with adding `email` in single quote:

```
   string query = "select name from userdetails where emailid='" + email +"';";
```

or 
 you can use parametrized query like this :

```
string query="select name from userdetails where emailid=@email" ;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
```