# c# database listbox item remove

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I making a database and I can add names, but I can't remove please help me.

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Recipe WHERE firstName = @user", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", cmds);
        cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    populateRecipe();
}
```

This is the error

> An unhandled exception of type `System.ArgumentException` occurred in `System.Data.dll Additional` information: No mapping exists from object type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Any errors that you can share?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: I have read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155004/difference-with-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue/9155103#9155103 that `cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue` is not a good way for work. It only send a `nvarchar` to the database instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the cmds itself to the AddWithValue method :

```
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", cmds);
```

I suppose you should pass your actual uesrname :

```
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
```

Comment: im done learning c# now i need to continue SQL Learning CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipe] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
it's my database

Comment: @Captain I suggest you learning Entity Framework. It's not only pretty easy to use but you will also enjoy dealing with it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `cmds` variable as the value for the `@user` parameter which doesn't make sense because it's a `SqlCommand` object:

```
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", cmds);
```

Don't you intend to pass the user's name that you want to delete instead?

```
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", "Username");
```