# Delete & Update query doesn't work in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I am trying to DELETE a record of Access Database using **OleDbCommand** class of **Connected Architecture**

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        String x = "Connection String...";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(x);
        con.Open();


        String query = "Delete FROM TB WHERE NO=@number";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", TextBox2.Text);


        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (res > 0)
        {
            Label.Text = "Deleted successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "Not Deleted";
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Every time I try deleting record **Else Condition** is executed which is NOT DELETED.

Same problem with **UPDATE** query,

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String x = "Connection String..";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(x);
        con.Open();


        String query = "UPDATE TB SET NM = @name WHERE NO = @TextBox_NO";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (res > 0)
        {
            Label.Text = "Updated successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "Not Updated";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

INSERT query works perfectly fine.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: convert TextBox2.Text to int

Comment: You should [never use](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: I know nothing of ASP.NET but I do know MS Access. And `NO` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe). Hence, if reserved words are used may result in unexpected answers or errors when referenced as fields.

To resolve, consider bracketing the `NO` column in both delete and update queries.

```
String query = "DELETE FROM TB WHERE [NO] = @number"

String query = "UPDATE TB SET NM = @name WHERE [NO] = @TextBox_NO"
```

I can confirm this solution as I just tested a `NO` vs `[NO]` column reference in a SQL query in MS Access 2013. The former returned zero records but latter returned correct records.

Answer (score 2):

i think there is any `datatype` `conversion error`, that's why  it's not deleting, and for the update case you just missed the parameter to pass `@name,@TextBox_No`

**See here Why to use [Add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155004/difference-with-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)**

You need to change parameter passing method [AddedWithValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.90).aspx) to [Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Delete:**

```
String query = "Delete FROM TB WHERE NO=@number";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.Numeric, 30).Value=TextBox2.Text;

        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (res > 0)
        {
            Label.Text = "Deleted successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "Not Deleted";
        }

        con.Close();
```

> and for Update u missed the parameter to pass:

```
String x = "Connection String..";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(x);
        con.Open();


        String query = "UPDATE TB SET NM = @name WHERE NO = @TextBox_NO";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@name ", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value=your_Name_Variable;//

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextBox_NO", OleDbType.Numeric, 30).Value=Your_No_Variable;

        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (res > 0)
        {
            Label.Text = "Updated successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "Not Updated";
        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Error: cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.Numeric, 30)=TextBox2.Text; 

Left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

Comment: Try, `cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.Numeric, 30).Value=TextBox2.Text;`

@Palak

Comment: Your answer has made some good points but I am not getting desired output.

Comment: `not getting desired output`,(so, there must be any problem), so, whats the problem?@Palak

Comment: Check out the solution by Parfait

Answer (score 1):

If it's not deleting any record that means `int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is returning 0 or no records deleted. Make sure that the condition in your `WHERE` clause `WHERE NO=@number` matches any record. To validate run a select along the line with the same condition

```
SELECT 1 FROM TB WHERE NO=@number
```

Also, try trimming the textbox data before punching as parameter like

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
```

If `NO` is of type `INT` then covert it to integer before passing as parameter like

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text.Trim()));
```

You can follow the same rules for your `UPDATE` case as well. Also, I don't see you are passing any parameter for your `UPDATE` query. Did you just skipped that in posted code?

```
    String query = "UPDATE TB SET NM = @name WHERE NO = @TextBox_NO";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
```

Comment: And don't use AddWithValue!

Comment: @Rahul can you explain how trim would make a difference?

Comment: @Palak, Trim would definitely make a difference in case there is a space in your textbox data and in which case the `WHERE` clause will be false definitely. Hope that make sense.

Comment: @Palak, that's why both delete/update doesn't work. Hope you got my point now.