# ASP.NET - VB.NET - SQL Server Express 2012 - Storing dates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to get the selected date from the Calender Control and store it to a column in the DB.

I'm getting the following error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Date of Birth DB column:

[image]

VB.Code for registration page:

```
        Public Sub register()



        Dim Username As String = txtUsername.ToString
        Dim Surname As String = txtSurname.ToString
        Dim Password As String = txtPassword.ToString
        Dim Name As String = txtName.ToString
        Dim Address1 As String = txtAddress1.ToString
        Dim Address2 As String = txtAddress2.ToString
        Dim City As String = txtCity.ToString
        Dim Email As String = txtEmail.ToString
        Dim Country As String = drpCountry.ToString
        Dim DOB As Date = calDOB.SelectedDate.Date
        Dim Occupation As String = txtOccupation.ToString
        Dim WorkLocation As String = txtWorkLocation.ToString
        Dim Age As Integer = "20"

        lblDOB.Text = DOB.ToString
        lblDOB.Visible = True


        Dim ProjectManager As String = "test"
        Dim TeamLeader As String = "test"
        Dim TeamLeaderID As Integer = "1"
        Dim ProjectManagerID As Integer = "1"

        Dim RegistrationDate As Date = DateTime.Today
        Dim ContractType As String = "test"
        Dim ContractDuration As Integer = 6
        Dim Department As String = "test"

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim registerSQL As SqlCommand
        Dim sqlComm As String

        sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, " +
            "City, Country, date_of_birth, age, Occupation, department, work_location, " +
            "project_manager,team_leader, team_leader_id, project_manager_id, " +
            "date_registration, contract_type, contract_duration) " +
            "VALUES(@p1, @p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15," +
            "@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20)"

        conn.Open()
        registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Username)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Password)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Name)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Surname)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Address1)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Address2)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", City)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", Country)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DOB)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", Age)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", Occupation)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", Department)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", WorkLocation)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", ProjectManager)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", TeamLeader)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", TeamLeaderID)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", ProjectManagerID)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", RegistrationDate)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", ContractType)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", ContractDuration)




        registerSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()


    End Sub



End Class
```

Exception Trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=16
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=1
  Message=String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
  Number=8152
  Procedure=""
  Server=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=13
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Registration.register() in C:\Users\Brian\Google Drive\Dropbox\Dropbox\THESIS\ThesisApp\Registration.aspx.vb:line 89
       at Registration.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Brian\Google Drive\Dropbox\Dropbox\THESIS\ThesisApp\Registration.aspx.vb:line 14
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

**UPDATE:** Added new error message, as I fixed the **RegistrationDate** and **DOB**. Now I'm getting a new error message:

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: @marc_s I still get the same error!

Comment: What **value** does `DOB` have when you assign it to the parameteR?? Also: are there any other columns of type `DATETIME` involved here? Is there a trigger on the table that might insert a new into an audit table with a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: @marc_s Dim RegistrationDate As Date = Today but its stopiing on the DOB

Comment: @Brian your field lengths are 20 characters wide i.e nchar(20) .. is any of your entered field greater than 20 characters?  the error `String or binary data would be truncated` indicates length of data being inserted is greater than column length.

Comment: It looks like you need to use Option Strict On ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ) because you are trying to assign strings to integers, e.g. `Dim Age As Integer = "20"`, so there could be other problems which the option will highlight for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some use
http://jwcooney.com/2012/09/10/asp-net-choosing-parameters-add-or-parameters-addwithvalue/

esp.the second point  *Implicit Data Conversions Cause Data Errors*

.. `You can accidentally introduce data errors if you use the Parameters.AddWithValue syntax to send a date datatype to your database, then you are at the mercy of the database to identify how it will store your date value. This can lead to problems since there are numerous ways of entering dates: mm/dd/yyyy in North America, dd/mm/yyyy in the UK, and yyyy-mm-dd as an upcoming standard. The database will look at the date value of 1/2/2012 that you are sending and can handle the ’1′ as either the day or as the month.`

I would recommend using :

```
registerSQL.Parameters.Add("@p9", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DOB.Date
```

instead of    `registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DOB)`

make sure `DOB` is not `DateTime.MinValue` or `DateTime.MaxValue`

Also refer to this question:

[Difference between adding parameters to stored procedure in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445663/difference-between-adding-parameters-to-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I echo this answer - I have encountered this sort of problem when using AddWithValue.

Answer (score 0):

What **value** does `DOB` have when you assign it to the parameter `@p9`??

Or could `RegistrationDate` be the culprit? What **value** does that variable have when you assign it to parameter `@p18` ??

This error would typically occur if you have a `DATETIME` column in SQL Server and you're trying to insert `NULL` from a .NET application into it - that gets converted to `01/01/0001` which is outside the value range of `DATETIME`.

Therefore my recommendation: use `DATE` (if you need only date - no time) or `DATETIME2` (for both date and time) in SQL Server **2008 and newer** (`DATETIME2` does **not** have these value range restrictions as `DATETIME` has)

Comment: So `Dim DOB As Date = calDOB.SelectedDate` and then `registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DOB)` supposedly should work 'out-of-the-box' ?

Comment: @Brian: sure - but **what value** is `calDOB.SelectedDate` in your case?? Is it a real value or is it `NULL` by any chance??

Comment: `calDOB.SelectedDate #3/15/2013# Date`

Comment: @Brian: well the new error messages just means you're setting **at least** one string parameter to a string that's **longer** than what is defined in the database table; you mostly have `nvarchar(20)` - so make sure none of your strings are longer than 20 characters when you set the parameters !

Comment: how will I know which one is the problem? As almost all my fields are nchar(20) or nchar(50) and I'm only entering one character in the textboxes?

Comment: @Brian: just look at the length of your strings that you're setting as values for the parameters before you call `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - which one is longer than 20 (or 50) characters? That's the problem case...